# Contour plot of the imaginary portion of a function given the real part is positive

Tags: plotting, complex, logarithmic-scale

How do I plot the imaginary part of the function while its real part is positive?

For example, for the below code I could have the imaginary part but I am not able to find the positive or negative real part of the function.

```
ContourPlot[{Im[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]]}, {x, -6, 8}, {y, -6, 6}, Contours -> {0}]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[Im[x + I y - Log[x + I y]], {x, -6, 8}, {y, -6, 6}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Re[x + I y - Log[x + I y]] > 0]]`

Comment: Hi Raul, for this command, are we first picking up the values of x and y, that satisfies the Re()>0, and then it plots the imaginary part? If so, If I want to add one more function in to this plot, How could I do it? Thank you

Comment: @Rahul, in this case, say I also want to plot this function x + I y - 4*Log[x + I *y] - 4 + 4*Log[4], how could I plot both in the same plot? Thank you

Comment: In that case you have to think about what you want drawn in the region where the real part of both functions is positive.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting this to put Rahul's answer, given in a comment to the question, on record.

```
ContourPlot[Im[x + I y - Log[x + I y]], {x, -6, 8}, {y, -6, 6},
  Contours -> {0}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Re[x + I y - Log[x + I y]] > 0]]
```

[image: plot]

The yellow regions are positive and the blue regions are negative.

The plot can be much cleaner if a nicer `ColorFunction` is used and the cutoff at `Re[function]==0` is not so abrupt:

```
ContourPlot[Im[x + I y - Log[x + I y]], {x, -2, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 Contours -> 16, (* 16 contours seemed like a good number *)
 BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Gray}, (* this adds a nice line at the edge of the region *)
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Re[x + I y - Log[x + I y]] > 0], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap" (* cool colors are negative, warm - positive *)
]
```

[image: plot2]

There's still an artifact at `y==0 && x<0`. This is to be expected, `Log[z]` has a branch-cut on the negative real half-line.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[
 If[Re[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]] > 0, Im[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]], 0],
 {x, -6, 8}, {y, -6, 6}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, 
Contours -> {0}]
```

Comment: Hi @David, this command works but, there occurs a zigzag line, which I believe is the contour (Re()) picture of the function. Say, our function is     x + I y - 4*Log[x + I *y] - 4 + 4*Log[4]  , in this case, that zigzag line turns out to be a half infinity sign , which I don't want it to be in the plot. Would you please let me know if I could do something with it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) and set its default to an imaginary number so that nothing is plotted for default values.

```
ContourPlot[
 Piecewise[{{
    Im[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]],
    Re[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]] > 0}}, I],
 {x, -6, 8}, {y, -6, 6},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 Contours -> 16,
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Or you can restrict the plot to a region

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[Re[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]] > 0,
    {{x, -6, 8}, {y, -6, 6}}];

ContourPlot[
 Im[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]],
 {x, y} ∈ reg,
 Contours -> 16,
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

For comparison purposes,

```
Plot3D[Im[x + I*y - Log[x + I*y]],
 {x, y} ∈ reg,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since V 12.1 there are [ComplexContourPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexContourPlot.html) as well as [ComplexRegionPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexRegionPlot.html)

```
ComplexContourPlot[Im[z - Log[z]], {z, -2 - 6 I, 6 + 6 I},
 BoundaryStyle -> {Thickness[0.004], GrayLevel[0.5]},
 ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones" ,
 Contours -> 16,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, Re[z - Log[z]] > 0]]
```

[image]

```
ComplexRegionPlot[
  {Re[z - Log[z]] < 0, Im[z - Log[z]] < 0}, {z, -2 - 6 I, 6 + 6 I},
  PlotLabels -> {"Re", "Im"}]
```

[image]